# How add and show the decimal dynamically after entering the number in number text field

Tags: javascript, validation, jquery-mobile, decimal

I have input field like number input field and max-length is 9. i need to add dynamically commas and last i need to put decimall like this .000.

I successfully adding commas but i not able adding the decimal.

If user enter max length or below max length i need to add decimal value.any body please help me how to do.

I need like 6,466,456.000 and 6,466.000

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.commas', function() {
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return comma_int(value) + '.000';
    });
});

function comma_int(value) {
  return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<div id="comprehensiveIns" class="carInsurance">
         <div class=showError txtVehicleValue_CI_carQuote_qa">
           <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="vehicleValue" id="txtVehicleValue_CI_carQuote_qa" placeholder="Vehicle Value" class="clearTxtFld commas" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==9 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;">
         </div>
```

[image]

Comment: 1. You say in your description that the input has a max-length of 9 but this is not in your code.  2. Can the digits after the decimal point be edited by the user or must it always be exactly .000?

Comment: Lesley..i modified the code please find and yes must it always be exactly .000.If user want edit only value not .000